# activityIndicator not appearing

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiwebview, spinner, uiactivityindicatorview

I have put an `activtyIndicator` on my `webView` and connected it with the files owner. I have an rss feed from a `tableView` and when I click on a cell, it pushes to the `webView`. Just like this tutorial. [RSS Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2636/how-to-make-a-simple-rss-reader-iphone-app-tutorial)

However, when the `webView` starts loading, the `activityIndicator` doesn't appear at all. The code for my `webView` file for the `activityIndicator` is below:

```
-(void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    [activityIndicator startAnimating];
    activityIndicator.hidden = NO;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];
}

-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
    activityIndicator.hidden = YES;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:FALSE];
}
```

Any ideas guys?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you actually add the UIActivityIndicatorView as a subView of your UIWebView? Did you set the frame of the UIActivityIndicatorView? Perhaps create a frame like `CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 32.0f, 32.0f); activityIndicatorView.center = webView.center;`

Comment: @Wolfgang Schreurs: I did not add the `activityIndicator` as a subView. Just placed a normal `activityIndicator` in IB. It works for the rest of my files, but just not this one for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common mistake is that you forget to set the delegate of the webview: `[theWebView setDelegate: self];`

Do you do that already? Or, if you put any NSLog() in your `webViewDidStartLoad`, do you see the output?

Comment: I have connected the `webView` delegate in IB as a referencing outlet. Also, my `NSLog()` does output as well. Quite weird that it's not showing up because it does on my other pages. Do you have any more ideas? Thanks.

Comment: So you can see the network activity indicator on the status bar (top left), but not your custom activityIndicatorView, right?

Comment: Yes, the network activity indicator on the status bar is spinning. I have placed a `UILabel` on it too, and that shows up when it's loading and disappears when it's stops loading. However, the `activityIndicator` just sits there and doesn't spin. I have checked that I have connected it to file's owner in IB too. Very weird. Thanks.

Comment: Hmm, strange. Please double check that your outlet is connected to the proper activity indicator view. Try to change its style in code, just to be sure that you are referencing the correct view.

Comment: How can I change it's style? Can you give me an example? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, my bad - you can set the style only in the init. Try to change something else, like the center for example: [activityIndicator setCenter:CGPointMake(50, 50)];

Comment: @K.Honda let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1155/discussion-between-irene-and-k-honda)

Comment: Hey, not sure why but after I fixed the pushing problem I had last night, and re-wrote the code for the `webView`; it worked. Haha. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Bring your subview to front. `[self bringSubViewToFront:activityindicator];`

Comment: My `activityIndicator` isn't on a subView unfortunately. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, (having a UIActivityIndicator on top of my UIWebView), and couldn't see the activity indicator.  This is what I did:

Put the activity indicator behind the uiwebview and initially hide the uiwebview, then when loading show the activity indicator.  When it is finished loading hide the spinner and show the uiwebview.

```
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    [spinner startAnimating];
    [spinner setHidden:FALSE];
    [loadButton setHidden:TRUE];
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    [spinner stopAnimating];
    [myWebView setHidden:FALSE];
}
```